# Time dilation & Pions - Why Both Stationary and Moving Pions Should not See the Same Result?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, time-dilation, observers, pions

One of the [proofs for time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_testing_of_time_dilation) is how [pions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion) travel further than they should as their lifetime expands due to their travelling near speed of light.

Now imagine you have 2 pions: one stationary on Earth called A the other accelerated to the near speed of light called B.

We do not need clocks as we do have 2 clocks on each particle: their life time. We consider that 1 unit.

- **A:** sees it dies in 1 unit.
- **B:** sees it dies in 1 unit

**A:** does not see B die, or if we have pions being created and dying, we will see 1xG pions, with G calculated based on the speed of B.

Now since this is a very **symmetrical** situation, even if we consider acceleration of B, both A and B see the other accelerating and drifting away at same speeds. In other words, if you are standing on A and consider A stationary, you see B accelerating to its speed and drifting away. By the same token, if you are standing on B, you see A and Earth and all do the same.

However, what we see in the experiments is different. We see A decays in 1 unit and B in G units from A standpoint.

In fact, if we are standing on B, we see G x pions decay in 1 unit of B.

How can we explain this despite the very symmetrical nature of the experiment?

> - Some points after reading comments:
>
>   I may not have been clear in my question.
>   My main question here is not about measuring pion life cycle.
>   It is rather how time dilation looks like a one way street.
>   One can imagine a particle like pion and do a thought experiment.
>
>   Take away Lab and Earth and just leave two observers on pions.
>   The reason I brought poins in the picture was because of Don Lincoln
>   from Fermalib explanations here:
>
>   [Relativity: how people get time dilation wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svwWKi9sSAA)
>
>   [Einstein's Clocks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Txv7V_nY2eg)
>
>   I have watched his other videos but still not convinced why the
>   symmetry in my thought experiment of having two observers sitting on
>   both pions should see things differently. To me both should see
>   the other one age slower!
>   Then how Lincoln's explanation in first clip stands?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when one particle accelerates you do not have symmetric situation. The physics in accelerated frame is different, there are suddenly new pseudoforces which are not present in an inertial frame. You are right, that if observer on B only observers position, he sees the other pion accelerate. But he can observer other things also, like the mentioned pseudoforces, which breaks the symmetry.

> We see A decays in 1 unit and B in G units from A standpoint.
> In fact, if we are standing on B, we see G x poins decay in 1 unit of B.

You say this is experimental result, but from which experiment? It does not seem right. If both pions A and B are inertial, then A should see B living longer than A and so should B see A living longer. They would not agree on how many A lifetimes the pion B lives as you are claiming.

Comment: Symmetrical in the sense that A sees B accelerate in the same way (in a diff direction of course) B accelerates. You can be on A observing B accelerating or on B observing A accelerating.  The fact that one is on Earth does not make it different!


Experiments here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_testing_of_time_dilation

As well as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Txv7V_nY2eg

Comment: @TheITGuy Symmetry in the sense you mentioned is not symmetry of physical laws. You asked "How can we explain this despite the very symmetrical nature of the experiment" and I told you if one of the pion is accelerated, the nature of experiment is not symmetrical at all.

Comment: @TheITGuy ok, I watched the video and read the wiki page, I have not seen any mentioning of "if we are standing on B, we see G x poins decay in 1 unit of B." This is simply wrong. Both (in this case inertial) pions will see each other decay in G units of their lifetime. But keep in mind the statistical nature of lifetime and that you really need beam of pions instead of one pion as annav explained.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Watch this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svwWKi9sSAA Based on this Lincoln calculates time seen from B should see A decay 1/Gth of the unit, right? On the point of symmetry, if symmetry is violated when B is accelerated, how so? Are you saying the direction of acceleration makes the difference? Because from B standpoint, A accelerates too, on a different direction. If we stand on B, then how things become different from when we are standing on A? Everything is the same no matter whether you stand on A or B except that A is with Earth!

Comment: @TheITGuy "Everything is the same no matter whether you stand on A or B..." it is not. As I said, in an accelerated frame there are additional pseudoforces which are not present in inertial frame. This means accelerated frame is not equivalent to inertial one.

Comment: @TheITGuy "Based on this Lincoln calculates time seen from B should see A decay 1/Gth of the unit, right" No. Imagine that some light bulb flashes in the hands of observer 1 at time $t_1$ and there is similar flash at the same time from his perspective from light bulb in the hands of observer 2. The two flashes are simultanenous w.r.t to observer 1 and happens at the time $t_1$. He then says, that observer 2 will see the flash from observer 1 hands at the time $t_2=\gamma t_1$ and he will see the flash from the light bulb in his own hands at the time $t_2'=t_1 /\gamma$...

Comment: @TheITGuy (cont.) The two flashes do not happen at the same time w.r.t to observer 2. This is not applicable for pion experiment, because the pions do not decay at the same time w.r.t. to neither one so the whole computation is not applicable. In this case the analysis at 3:30 is true (but only if the movement is inertial), both think the others time is slowed down. This is nothing weird, as the perception is not objective but subjective and there is no problem with two observers percieving the same thing differently.

Comment: @TheITGuy P.S. "observer 2 will see the flash" ... to be clear, the seeing must be understood in the sense that "event light bulb of observer 1 flashing and event observer 2 sees time $t_2$ are simultaneous". As it takes time for light to reach observer 2, he will actually sees the flash later.

Comment: @ Umaxo Let us assume a different thought experiment to rid of acceleration altogether. Imagine observer A and B have been moving relative to each other from infinite long ago and they reach a point at the same time when each produce a pion. That will be very symmetrical, right? Then what? Shouldn't both see the same thing, i.e. A seeing longer decay time of B pion AND B seeing longer decay time of A pion?

Comment: @TheITGuy add one more assumption for simplicity that each pion is stationary in the frame of observer which produced it.... " A seeing longer decay time of B pion AND B seeing longer decay time of A pion" Yes, that is what I repeated 3 times already.

Answer (score 1):

> We do not need clocks as we do have 2 clocks on each particle: their life time. We consider that 1 unit.

Pions are quantum mechanical entities. They do not have clocks. They are mathematically described by a complex number wavefunction $Ψ$ which has the mathematical information on the probability of the given pion to decay ,given by $Ψ^*Ψ$ , real numbers, so observable. To see probabilities one has to accumulate a statistically significant  number of pions at a given energy , i.e. in a given inertial frame. In the inertial frame of a pion at rest is the lifetime of the pion found in the PDG tables.

So the possible experiments are:

1. pions at rest, and register the time t from their creation ( in an interaction,) to their decay.
2. create a beam of pions at a given momentum and energy (four vector) and register the number of pions at the time from the creation of the beam to the number remaining after certain time intervals, to get a lifetime plot. It is a much more complicated experiment to get the lifetime from cosmic rays, [but it can be done](https://www.hep.physik.uni-siegen.de/teaching/masterlab2019/Manuals2019/mupi_2019.pdf)  as an exersize for students.

Pions cannot "see" each other, they can only interact with various possible forces. Your experiment treats pions as classical particles obeying  relativistic equations, but they are not, they follow quantum mechanical relativistic kinematics which only predict probability distributions.So it is a science fiction experiment.

Comment: Well, I was not really talking about true clocks but rather thought experiment clocks. Imagine you are on a pion and see it decay in 2.6 x 10-8 seconds. I consider that to be a unit of time for the observer on the poin.  No other clocks needed. Just the lifecycle of poins.

Comment: Please see this clip. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Txv7V_nY2eg Dr Lincoln mentions there is a real experiment involving poins!

Comment: It is pions not poin, which you keep writing wrong. Of course there aref experiments with pions, even as exercise for masters students as the one in the link  I give. But the way to see their lifetime and time dilation is through quantum mechanical equations .

Comment: A similar experiment is done using mu-mesons and is available on youtube (I am not able to link it here for some reason but I have given the name) :'Time Dilation : An Experiment With Mu - Mesons (1962)' . There explanation should probably clear your doubts.Pay careful attention to the fact that in the frame of reference of  mesons coming from above the length contraction of mountain is considered  while time dilation is given emphasis  for the  mesons in the Lab as they 'look' at the upcoming mesons.

Comment: I do not see the point of this nitpicking. The clocks of pion is just identified with some clocks in the frame which is at rest w.r.t to the pion. Pion "seeing" something is just shorthand for "from the point of view of observer at rest with the pion".

Comment: @Umaxo But you cannot measure the lifetime with one pion, is all I am saying, and so time dilation . Only in the distribution of many pions the lifetime  can be seen  and compared  to the lifetime at rest

Comment: @annav I do not disagree with you on this point.

Comment: @TheITGuy A pion at rest does *not* have a fixed decay time, it isn't like an alarm clock. The time it takes to decay is a statistical thing, as per usual with quantum events. A (charged) pion has a [mean lifetime](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_lifetime) of ~26.033 ns, in other words, it has a half-life of ~18.045 ns. So if you start with 1,024,000 pions (at non-relativistic speeds, relative to the lab frame), after 180 ns you'd expect that around 1000 of them won't have decayed yet.

Comment: @annav Thanks for your detailed explanations. My main concern, however, is not pions itself. I mentioned pions as per Don Lincoln experiments trying to prove time dilation. He, in another video explains time dilation is one way street.

My main question is what difference should it make if you are observer on A or B. From what I understand A should see B ages slower in the same way B sees A ages slower. In Don Lincoln case and in Twin Paradox (which is not exactly the same) it is only one way street. I do not see why a very symmetrical case yields asymmetrical result!

Comment: @annav Here is the clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svwWKi9sSAA 

BTW, I guess the reason you are not able to post YouTube links in comments is either because only original poster can or you may need to collect some points before you do.  I am not too sure and I would do the same as you would if this did not allow me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I see where you're coming from. Let me try to restate the problem in maybe a more precise way.

In this scenario a pion decays exactly 1 unit of time after its creation (in the frame of the pion). There's no probabilistic element.

According to the observer on earth, at a particular moment pion A pops into existence at rest in the lab and pion B pops into existence high up in the atmosphere traveling at a high speed toward the ground.

According to this observer, the "clock" attached to pion B is ticking slowly and so pion B lives longer than pion A. The observation is that at the moment pion A decays pion B is still alive.

This seems like a paradox since the observation "A dead, B alive" seems like a physical invariant. I.e. an observer attached to pion B will also see pion A decay while pion B is still alive. In fact, let's set up the experiment so that pion A decays at the exact moment the two pions meet. Then we really have a local measurement that observers traveling with either A and B agree on. At the moment the two pions meet A is dead and B is alive. This fact has gotta be the same for every observer. And it is.

But the situation is totally symmetric, right?

Actually it's not. The key is back at the beginning when the two pions were created at the same time *according to the observer on the earth*. In fact, according to the observer attached to pion B the two are *not* created at the same time. This is the relativity of simultaneity. According to the observer traveling with pion B, pion A is created long before pion B is. And even though observer B sees pion A take longer than 1 unit to decay (time dilation), pion A was created so much earlier than pion B that by the time the two pions meet pion A has decayed but B hasn't. So the two observers really do agree on the observation AND, crucially, both see the other's clock ticking slow!

Comment: Thanks sums up well with one correction until your restating the question: "But the situation..." Let's assume the particle created artificially and at the same time, same as in Dr Lincoln's experimetn, and then one is accelerated but not the other. Then we should have full symmetry, right?

Comment: I don't know what Dr. Lincoln's experiment is, but what you describe does not have full symmetry. I think you're saying that in the Earth frame both particles are created at rest and at the same time and afterward pion B is accelerated toward the ground. But then in this case an observer attached to pion B is not an inertial observer, while an observer attached to A is inertial. So we shouldn't expect exact symmetry in what they think happens.

Comment: I know this isn't a complete explanation because it doesn't tell the story from B's perspective but the non-inertial frame will be the key in breaking the symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that the time dilation equation in SR relates to a fundamentally asymmetrical scenario- it compares the time at a single place in one frame with the time at two different places in another.   That's the key to it.

So in your pion example, Pion B might age a millisecond in its own frame while passing between two points on Earth, and the time difference between those two points might be a second, say, in the Earth frame. The symmetry is that while the 'stationary' Pion A ages a millisecond, it moves between two places in the frame of Pion B, and the time difference between those two points in the Pion B frame will be a second.

So time dilation applies when you compare the time on a single clock with the times on two separate clocks it passes, and the time on the single clock is always less than the time difference between the two separated clocks. It doesn't matter which you consider to be moving. If I sit in my chair and I am passed in turn by two spaceships moving in convoy, the time that passes on my watch will be less than the time difference according to clocks on the two spaceships. Even though the ships are moving relative to me, the readings on the two clocks will seem 'time contracted' to me, not time dilated, because I am comparing time at a single place in my frame with the time at two different places in the spaceship frame.